# Shouldn't DISCARD PLANS re-evaluate every function definition in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, functions, materialized-view

Hi have a set of functions that take a row of a table (let's call it bookings) as input parameters. Some of these functions call other functions, and they are used to calculate a materialized view.

So far so good.

The I decided that the table column "booking_date" should not be a timestamp, but instead a date:

`ALTER TABLE booking ALTER booking_date TYPE DATE;`

This booking table had views over it that I previously dropped (also triggers, but those I kept as it had no effect).

Then, when I try to recreate the materialized view (that uses those above mentioned functions), I get the following error message:

```
Message    : ERROR: date out of range for timestamp
  Where: PL/pgSQL function calcfee(booking) while storing call arguments into local variables
```

But if I execute a second time, everything works as expected.

Then I read about [Plan Caching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING), and it starts to make sense - the functions are evaluated at session start (in this case, [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) running migrations), and since the underlying table has changed, the cache should be invalidate.

Hence, I tried (as described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-discard.html)):

```
DISCARD PLANS;
```

To no result.

However, this brute-force approach did the trick:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.recreate_functions()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare f record;
BEGIN
  -- query postgres for 'user functions definitions'
  FOR f IN select pg_get_functiondef(pp.oid) as fdef from pg_proc pp inner join pg_namespace pn on (pp.pronamespace = pn.oid) inner join pg_language pl on (pp.prolang = pl.oid) where pl.lanname NOT IN ('c','internal') and pn.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%' and pn.nspname <> 'information_schema' LOOP
    EXECUTE f.fdef;
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

-- DISCARD PLANS;
SELECT recreate_functions();
```

Why is that? What am I missing here?

Thanks